# Issue in pagination in react and supabase

Tags: reactjs, pagination, supabase

I am having issues with the pagination in ReactJS and Supabase. I want to display 15 records per page. I am getting 15 records on page 1, but on page 2, it displays no data. I have total 57 records in supabase.

The useState hook:

```
const { projectId } = useParams<{ projectId: string }>();
const [project, setProject] = useState<Project | null>(null);
const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState<number>(1);
const [recordsPerPage, setRecordsPerPage] = useState<number>(15);
const [count, setCount] = useState<number>(0);
```

The useEffect hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProject = async () => {
      try {
        const {
          data: drawingsData,
          error: drawingsError,
          count,
        } = await supabase
          .from("Drawings")
          .select("*", { count: "exact" })
          .eq("project_id", projectId)
          .range(
            (currentPage - 1) * recordsPerPage,
            (currentPage - 1) * recordsPerPage + recordsPerPage - 1
          );

        setCount(count!);

        setProject(drawingsData);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };

    fetchProject();
  }, [projectId, currentPage, recordsPerPage]);
```

The paginate methods:

```
const indexOfLastRecord = currentPage * recordsPerPage;
  const indexOfFirstRecord = indexOfLastRecord - recordsPerPage;
  const currentRecords = drawingsData?.slice(
    indexOfFirstRecord,
    indexOfLastRecord
  );
  const paginate = (pageNumber: number) => setCurrentPage(pageNumber);
  const pageNumbers = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(count / recordsPerPage); i++) {
    pageNumbers.push(i);
  }
```

The JSX element:

```
<div>
  {currentRecords?.map((drawing:any) => (
    // JSX content
  ))}

  <ul>
    <li className={`page-item previous ${currentPage === 1 ? "disabled" : "" }`}>
      <a href="#" onClick={() => paginate(currentPage - 1)}>
        <i></i>
      </a>
    </li>
    {[...Array(Math.ceil(count / recordsPerPage)).keys()].map((number) => (
      <li key={number + 1} className={`page-item ${currentPage === number + 1 ? "active" : ""}`}>
        <a href="#" className="page-link" onClick={() => paginate(number + 1)}>
          {number + 1}
        </a>
      </li>
    ))}
    <li className={`page-item next ${currentPage === Math.ceil(count / recordsPerPage) ? "disabled" : ""}`}>
      <a href="#" onClick={() => paginate(currentPage + 1)}>
        <i></i>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! First I would check if supabase actually returns any records. You can do this by opening up the network tab on your browser (right click->inspect element and there network).

If not, I would check the request you are sending. If it does, then I would assume the problem lies with pagination or the way you save data. Please provide more information if network tab inspection won't help :)

Comment: @kala I am getting 15 records in the consolw on page 1, After clicking on page 2 I am getting another 15 records. so data retrieving is not an issue, data rendering is the issue.